# Understanding boundedness in functions

Tags: functions

I am trying to get a better feel for the characteristic of boundedness of functions. For that I try to come up with a couple of examples. I would like to see if I got it right. I am not sure, if asking this is valid question. If not, I can delete the question.

---

When I define a function $f(x) = \frac1{x^2}$, I cannot write $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, but must write $f: \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb R$, because it is not defined in 0.

Yet, $f(x) = x^2$ is an $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, because for any $x\in\mathbb R$, I get an $f(x)\in\mathbb R$, even though $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) = \infty$ - which makes $f$ unbounded.

Let's say I define a function $f$

- $f(x) = \frac1{x^2}$ for $x\in\mathbb R, x\neq 0$
- $f(x) = 1$ for $x=0$

is it right to say that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and that $f$ is unbounded?

Comment: Yes, you are right - your $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. A function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there is some $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for any $x\in A$. If you define $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)=x^{-2}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$, $f$ is unbounded: for any fixed $M>0$, if $0<x<\sqrt{M}$, then $f(x)>M$. So $f$ is unbounded, regardless of what value you assign to $f(0)$.

Comment: Just to be clear: $f$ is unbounded if it is not bounded.